# convert xml to sql

Tags: php, sql, xml, parsing, split

I need to convert an XML file (about 200 Mb in size) to SQL files and insert them into a MySQL table (one table - it looks like there are about 10 million rows, only a few columns).

- Unfortunately, I don't have access to shell / command line tools
- It looks like I would need to use PHPMyAdmin import tool where the import size is limited to 50mb per upload
- Or, PHP is enabled via web browsers only, so write a PHP script to execute from the browser.

So, steps are (please let me know if there are better ways to go around):

- unpack the file into the server
- write a PHP script to convert and insert

or

- do it locally and use phpadmin to upload them separately

What would be a good way to get this done? any ideas / feedbacks / details are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is very good at dealing with xml data. You can parse the data with it and convert it to the format you need.

You might have an issue with the size of the file if you can't change the configuration though. I believe the default allowed memory size is ~8MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really dealing with 10 million rows, (200Mb of data, at 10 millows, rows, approx 21 bytes per row?), then unpacking the file on the server and writing a script to handle the insert's would probably be the best best.